# Laravel break and combine Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

in my one of actions in controller i have optional parameter as `id`, i want to use that when that's not NULL in Eloquent query chain, my code:

```
public function myInvoices($id = null)
{
    $invoices = PaymentPackages::whereUserId(auth()->user()->id)
        ->with(
            ['package' => function ($query) {
                $query->with(['features', 'panel']);
            }
            ]
        )->latest('id');

    if ($id != null) {
        $invoices->whereId($id);
    }

    $invoices->get();

    dd($invoices);
}
```

when i try to get result of this query on `dd` i get Builder result

```
Builder {#1355 ▼
  #query: Builder {#1354 ▶}
  #model: PaymentPackages {#1353 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: array:1 [▶]
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:12 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}
```

how can i resolve this problem to use `id` without writing other query with `id` parameter when that's not NULL?

Comment: The condition in this case is unavoidable because in one case you perform a `->get()` if you do not have an `$id` set, and in one other case you do a `->latest('id')` when the `$id` is set, so basically you *have* to do the distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't saving the query result:

```
$result = $invoices->get();
dd($result);
```

Comment: Could have just been a comment.

Comment: @AnwarNairi IMO, the solution should always be posted as an answer, even a short one. Like this, the OP can accept it and the issue is marked as resolved. A question that is only solved in the comments wastes the time of people who are looking for unanswered questions.